# Changing TextView Text Size in Custom List View in run time

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

I'm now implementing a custom `ListView`. When I tried to change the `TextView` that is located in `CustomAdaper.xml` from `MainActivity`. It show NullPointerException. Isn't it possible to do like this . Help me finding it Please . I get so confused .

Below is my **MainActivity.java** Code :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
txt_Position = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtposition);//still ok
txt_memberName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtmemberName);// still ok

LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) layout_Date.getLayoutParams();
LayoutParams params1 = (LayoutParams) layout_List.getLayoutParams();
LayoutParams params2 = (LayoutParams) layout_Rotation.getLayoutParams();

     int screenSize = getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
                Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

        switch(screenSize) {

        case Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Large", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            params.height = 100;
            params1.height = 330 ;
            params2.height = 200;
            txt_Position.setTextSize((float)18.0); //locate in CustomAdapter.xml and this is the line logCat Error Pointed .
            break;
```

CustomAdapter.Java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public Resources res;
ListModel getList;
int size ;
int i=0;


public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal, int size) {


    activity = a;
    data=d;
    res = resLocal;
    this.size = size;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


public int getCount() {

    if(data.size()<=0)
        return 1;
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


public static class ViewHolder{

    public TextView txt_Name;
    public TextView txt_Status;
    public TextView txt_Position;
    public ImageButton imgbtn_senka;
    public ImageButton imgbtn_fuenka;
    //public TableRow tblrow_btn;
    public RelativeLayout layoutbtn;
    public ImageView image;

}


public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View vi=convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView==null){

        /********** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) ************/
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customadapter, null);


        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_Name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberName);
        holder.txt_Status = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtmemberStatus);
        holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imgPlayer);
        holder.imgbtn_fuenka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnfusenka);
        holder.imgbtn_senka = (ImageButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.btnsenka);
        holder.txt_Position = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtposition);
        holder.layoutbtn = (RelativeLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.layoutbutton);

        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

    if(data.size()<=0)
    {
        holder.txt_Name.setText("No Data");

    }
    else
    {


        getList=null;
        getList = (ListModel) data.get(position);

        if(getList.getMemberStatus() == 3){


            holder.txt_Status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgbtn_senka.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if(getList.getEntry() == 1){

                holder.imgbtn_senka.setImageResource(R.drawable.sankagray);
                holder.imgbtn_senka.setEnabled(false);

            }

            else if(getList.getEntry() == 0){

                holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setImageResource(R.drawable.fusankagray);
                holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setEnabled(false);


            }

            holder.imgbtn_senka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String entry = "1";

                    CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
                    sct.updateData(position , entry);
                    holder.imgbtn_senka.setImageResource(R.drawable.sankagray);
                    holder.imgbtn_senka.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setImageResource(R.drawable.fusanka);



                }
            });

            holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String entry = "0";

                    CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;
                    sct.updateData(position , entry);
                    holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setImageResource(R.drawable.fusankagray);
                    holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setEnabled(false);
                    holder.imgbtn_senka.setEnabled(true);
                    holder.imgbtn_senka.setImageResource(R.drawable.sanka);



                }
            });
        }

        else{


            holder.txt_Status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imgbtn_fuenka.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            holder.imgbtn_senka.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if(getList.getEntry() == 0){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("未確認");
            }
            else if(getList.getEntry() == 1){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("参加");
            }

            else if(getList.getEntry() == 2){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("不参加");
            }
            else if(getList.getEntry() == 3){
                holder.txt_Status.setText("取消");
            }
        }





         holder.txt_Name.setText(getList.getMemberName());
         holder.txt_Position.setText(getList.getPosition());
         String url="http://10.0.2.2/football365/Photo/"+getList.getImage();

         try {
            Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent());
            Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 76, 76, false);
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(resized);
        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // holder.image.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier("http://10.0.2.2/football365/Photo/"+getList.getImage(),null,null));


    }

    if(size == 1){

        holder.txt_Name.setTextSize((float)20.0);

    }

    return vi;
}

public void changeSize(){

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.txt_Position.setTextSize((float)18.0);
    holder.txt_Name.setTextSize((float)20.0);
}
```

}

This is CustomAdapter.xml

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/tblrowtotal"
  android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
  android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
  android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
  android:background="@drawable/blackrow2"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imglin1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/liney" />

     <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >


     <ImageView
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:id="@+id/imgPlayer"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            style="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            android:background="@null"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:paddingTop="0dip" >

    <TableRow>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtmemberName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="13sp" />
    </TableRow>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/linex" />



    <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/position"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/c_position" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtposition"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/liney" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtmemberStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnfusenka"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:focusable="false"

                android:src="@drawable/fusanka"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnsenka"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="@null"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:src="@drawable/sanka"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/linex" />

</TableLayout>




</TableRow>
```

Comment: Is your TextView in CustomAdaper.xml?

Comment: Post your logcat for more information.

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta . Yes .

Comment: Can you post CustomAdaper class and xml file?

Comment: It's ok When I implement this code in getView method . But I would LIke to implement this in MainActicity :) Thanks for concern . I'll update the question with customAdapter.java and customerAdapter.xml .

Comment: Is Textview with id = txtposition located in activity_main?

Comment: @Piyush Gupta . I already updated :)

Comment: @user3032822, your textview located in customerAdapter.xml, and do you want to change the size of textview of one item or all?

Comment: @user3032822 If you are trying to set textSize of your textView which is in your customAdapter file then it will be given NPE everytime

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta , Yes :) I tried this out getView method in customerAdapter.java . It's work fine . Thanks for concern .

Comment: You can do it in your xml file, android:textSize="18sp"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
txt_Position.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, Float.parseFloat(18.0));
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
txt_Position.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```